# Cygwin: List processes with files they are accessing

Tags: cygwin, ps

I am looking for a way to list all files used by a specified running process

I have a script that loops into zip files in an archive directory tree (one directory for each day) and extracts some information

The script takes long so I executed it in the format "nohup ./script.sh &"

I was wondering if there's a command that shows which zip file 'unzip -p' is currently working on

I have tried all parameters mentioned in the ps --help and none of them did the trick.

Are there any other commands that show which file(s) are currently used by a specific process?

Thanks in advance and happy holidays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `/proc` filesystem with the PID of the process

In this example I used a less process with PID 10904

```
$ ps | grep less
I   10904   15292   10904       9792  pty3      197609 12:00:17 /usr/bin/less

$ ls /proc/10904/fd/
0  1  2  3  4

$ ls -l /proc/10904/fd/4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Marco Kein 0 Dec 24 12:02 /proc/10904/fd/4 -> /tmp/test5-b2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer matzeri, it's an interesting source of information to say the least
I couldn't find a symlink 4 in my example, so no files were used. Does this work when I use a pipe to grep the output of the unzip -p command?

Comment: It actually worked on the second attempt. Thanks again for the reply ;)